# Making an image black and white in python without pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, matplotlib, grayscale

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img=mpimg.imread('2048.png')

a = np.zeros_like(img)

for j in xrange(img.shape[0]):
    for i in xrange(img.shape[1]):
        a[j,i] = np.mean(img[j,i])

imgplot = plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

This is what I have so far and it works, but it's very slow because it only edits 1 pixel at the time, what is a clever way of using arrays to make an image grey? And I can't use functions like convert("L").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to unutbus answer, you might also want to take care when converting to grayscale: uniform weighting (taking the mean) is not the only, or necessarily correct, way to go.

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)

> Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B

which translates into

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
arr = 0.2126* img[...,0] + 0.7152* img[...,1] + 0.0722 * img[...,2]
plt.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

**Note in response to question**

The array is now stored in `arr` which you can now manipulate as you please.

**Silhouette**

If you need a silhouette / mask, you can use simple thresholding

```
bw = arr > 0.3
plt.imshow(bw)
plt.show()
```

No need to add in the colormap argument, though the default is `jet`, which will display as blue and red for a binary image.

**Output**

To save the image you can use `plt.savefig` which will use the colormap applied to the image. This means if you want a grayscale image you need to specify the 'gray' colormap

Alternatively using e.g. `scipy.misc.imsave` will save a 2d matrix as grayscale. Other libraries you could use include the [png module](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html)

Comment: At least I can make a silhouette now with arr[arr>0.3] = 1 arr[arr<=0.3] = 0 plt.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
Is there a way to do it without the cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray')) argument?

Comment: @user3585279: Added section about the silhouette.

Comment: And how about saving the grey / silhouette image? When I try to save it now with imsave it saves it in all the strange colours / blue and red.

Comment: If you need it to be grayscale, you either need to specify the gray colourmap, or use a different library to save the image. Updated with example

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
arr = img.mean(axis=-1)
plt.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's the true result. OP's `a` is still 3-d array. also can be represented as `arr = (img.mean(axis=-1)*256).astype(np.uint8)` for 8-bit quantization.

Comment: And is there a way to print/return the array so I can use it to make a silhouette of it later?

Comment: Because I need the array of the grey image using arguments  in plt.imshow to make it grey isn't really an option.